# Inverting $f(x)=\frac{a^x-1}{a^x +1}$

Tags: inverse, solution-verification, elementary-functions

This is the problem:

$$f(x)= \frac{a^x-1}{a^x+1}, \quad a > 0, \quad a \ne 1.$$

What I can get, but I don't think it is right:

$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{-x-1}{x \ln a-\ln a}.$$

So this is what I did:

$$x=\frac{a^y-1}{a^y+1}$$
$$xa^y+x=a^y-1$$
$$xa^y-a^y=-x-1$$
$$xy\ln(a)-y\ln(a)=-x-1$$
$$y(x\ln(a)-ln(a))$$
$$y=\frac{-x-1}{x\ln(a)-\ln(a)}$$

Solution:$$y=\frac{\ln\frac{-(x+1)}{x-1}}{\ln(a)}$$

Comment: Can you show your work? And please format your equations next time

Comment: Are you trying to find the inverse of the function $f(x)=\frac{a^x-1}{a^x +1}$? If so, say that in the question title. Showing the steps you took to get your attempted answer is also very useful. To format the formulas, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Yea sure and that was the thing i tried setting it up with the format but it wouldnt stick.  And thanks David

Comment: A $\LaTeX$ hint:  if you preceed common functions with a backslash, you get the right font.  \ln gives $\ln$ instead of ln giving $ln$  I fixed the title.  I think the site doesn't like titles that are all MathJax.

Comment: Thank you once again i am new to the site so still have to get used to a couple of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fine down to $xa^y-a^y=-x-1$, but you take the log on the left and not on the right.  When you do so, you assume the log of a sum is the sum of the logs, which is not correct.  You seem to be claiming that $\ln (xa^y-a^y)=xy\ln a - y\ln a$.  You should distribute out the $a^y$ to get$$(x-1)a^y=-x-1\\a^y=-\frac{x+1}{x-1}$$ now take logs and you are set.

Comment: so my final answer would be $$y=\frac{ln\frac{-(x+1)}{x-1}}{ln(a)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice, let $f(x)=y\implies x=f^{-1}(y)$

$$y=\frac{a^x-1}{a^x+1}$$ $$ya^x+y=a^x-1$$
$$a^x(1-y)=1+y$$ $$a^x=\frac{1+y}{1-y}$$
$$\ln(a^x)=\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)$$ $$x\ln a=\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)$$ $$x=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)}{\ln a}$$$$\implies f^{-1}(y)=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)}{\ln a}$$
$$\color{red}{f^{-1}(x)=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}{\ln a}=\log_a\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}$$
$\forall \ \ a>0,\ a\ne 1$

Answer (score 0):

Given $$\displaystyle \frac{f(x)}{1} = \frac{a^x-1}{a^x+1}\;,$$ Where $a>0\;,a\neq 1$

Now Using Componendo -Dividedno, We get

$$\displaystyle \frac{f(x)+1}{f(x)-1} = \frac{(a^x-1)+(a^x+1)}{(a^x-1)-(a^x+1)} = \frac{a^x}{-1}$$

So $$\displaystyle  \frac{a^x}{1} = \frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)}$$

Now $$\displaystyle \ln_{a}(a)^x = \ln\left(\frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)}\right)\Rightarrow x = \ln\left(\frac{1+f(x)}{1-f(x)}\right)\;,$$

Now Using Definition of Inverse, Replace $x\rightarrow f^{-1}(x)$ and $f(x)\rightarrow x$

So we get $$\displaystyle f^{-1}(x) = \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\;,$$ Where $a>0$ and $a\neq 1$

Answer (score 0):

You want to invert
$y= \frac{a^x-1}{a^x+1}
$.

Let
$z = a^x$.
Then you want to invert
$y = \frac{z-1}{z+1}
$.
$zy+y = z-1$,
so
$z(1-y) =1+y$
or
$z = \frac{1+y}{1-y}
$.

Finally,
$a^x= \frac{1+y}{1-y}
$
or
$x \ln a
=\ln(1+y)-\ln(1-y)
$.